# How can I take a variable from bash script and use it in java?

Tags: java, bash, shell

So this is my shell called setDate.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dateLaunch='$1'
```

This shell will be launched with a yyyyMMddHHmm variable, so it will be launched as **sh setDate.sh** 202109271640 for example.
I should take this **dateLaunch** variable ad use it in my java application to insert it into an sql table.
For now I'm using currentTimeMillis from the moment the shell and the java program are launched.

```
@Autowired
private Service service;
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
try {
   Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
   String formDate = timestamp.toString().substring(0,16);
   formDate = formDate.replaceAll("[\\-\\:\\s+]", "");
   service.insertIntoDateTable(formDate);

   return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}catch(Exception e) {
   log.error("Error xyz");
   throw e;


  }
 }
}
```

Is there a way I can take that dateLaunch variable and use it in my service.insertIntoDateTable? I should specify I'm using java 1.8.

Comment: Yes - pass it as a command line argument when you launch the Java app, and it will be present in the `String[]` parameter in your `main` method.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html